# Converting VF page into MS Word

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, rerender

I am trying to render VF page into MS Word, all content is appearing exactly as per requirement except border of MS Word.Please have a look of below screenshot.Tried many CSS but no effect on the border size.

Requirement is this, the border is going inside the header but when I am rendering my VF page as a MS Word file it is not coming.
[image]

My outbut is this:my page border is not going inside the header.like above
[image]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following css.

```
<style>
    /**
     * Sheet Settings
     */
    @page Section1{
        size:420mm 297mm;/*width height*/
        mso-page-orientation:landscape;
        margin-top:20mm;
        margin-bottom:20mm;
        margin-right: 30mm;
        margin-left:30mm;
    }

    /**
     * Range for one Sheet
     */
    div.Section1{
        page:Section1;
    }
</style>
```